# Drawing an entity-relationship diagram for a movie sales business domain

Tags: database-design, erd

I want to keep track of *movies* that exist in different *formats* (for example, DVD, Bluray, etc.). The *price* for each *format* differs from the others as well as the *quantity* of each *format*, so I came up with the entity-relationship diagram (ERD) shown below:

[image: example]

Is this correct from a design perspective? Does this implies redundancy? I don't understand how will this be retained in a table when implemented in a relational database.

Would it be better to do it like in the diagram that follows:

[image]

**Additional information**

Here's more descriptive information about what I want to store at this point of the design:

- I want to store information about *sales*.
- For each *movie* that exists in the company I need to keep *format*, *price* and *stock quantity*.
- I will also need to maintain *customer* information with a *unique id*, *name*, *surname*, *address*, *movies* that he/she has already *bought* and his/her *credit card number*.
- Finally, I will have a *basket* that temporary keeps *items* (let's suppose that other *items* exist apart from *movies*) that the *customer* wants to *buy*.

Answer (score 1):

I would use (title,prod_date) as the primary key, since movies are not uniquely identified by their title alone (remakes, for example). In my opinion, the first diagram is preferable, the sub-attribute approach in the second diagram seems a bit convoluted to me.

Comment: i updated the question with more info.

Comment: a1ex gives good suggestions. If this is going to be used in some real-life commercial system (as opposed to some school assignment) I would strongly recommend not storing credit card numbers - bad idea security-wise and illegal in some countries.

Comment: well its not gonna be for commercial systems but just for learning. I am just trying to optimise this as much as possible without opening too much the details of this db.

Answer (score 1):

I'd put in stock something like `movie_product` (assuming you are not going to sell anything but movies) which can look like

```
movie_product (movie_product_id ,
movie_id, format_id, manufacturer_id, date_produced,
--maybe some other attributes
)
```

You need to decide yourself what is important to store in the context of your domain (say, you don't care about manufacturer, so there is no need to store id, or, in contrast, it's important to have a flag specifying whether it's a special edition ). 
Then stock may look like

```
stock (stock_id, movie_product, current_quantity)
```

I guess price is changing, to deal with it I'd track it as a separate entity :

```
stock_price(stock_id, date_from,date_thru, price)
--no updates here, only inserts
```

Comment: I updated the question with more info. btw u confuse me with the relational representation :p Lets keep it at an ER level.